# Make gson NOT put quotes around field names

Tags: java, json, gson

Say I have a basic class in Java:

```
public class Person{
    public String name;
}
```

When I give an object, instantiated with the name of "bob", to gson to serialize, it comes back as :

```
{"name" : "bob"}
```

How can I make it so it gives me:

```
{name:"bob"}
```

I know this is a simple question, but I'm not finding anything to help me in the API, and I apparently don't know the terminology  well enough for json to do searches good enough to find the answer.

Comment: it's required by the JSON spec. Unquoted string keys are not permitted: http://json.org/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Yeah, as mentioned above, the JSON spec expects quotes.**

Now, if you really want your stuff, you can try creating your own [JSONWriter](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/source/browse/trunk/gson/src/main/java/com/google/gson/stream/JsonWriter.java)
 and passing it to `Gson.toJson(Object src, Type typeOfSrc, JsonWriter writer) throws JsonIOException`

Comment: Thanks, I was mixing up the info transport notation(JSON) with actual Javascript Objects.  Once you un-marshal the JSON into a Javascript Object, the string representation lacks the quotes around property names.